# Feed many sheets in one Excel file "Reporting" from 7 input files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba

Pyhon 3.7.3 Excel 10

14 Input files : .xls et 1 Template  : .xls

Output file : .xls (or better .xlsx)

The Template to feed contains pictures charts/graphs.
The copy of values in tables feed the graphs
I use xlrd library to read input files and xlwt, to write output files.
I tried to use openpyxl too : It's OK

But error :

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\header_footer.py:49: UserWarning: Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored
  warn("""Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Paul\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Paul\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 434, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Paul\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Paul\Documents\Applications\Traitement TDF\Entrée\Remplissage du Patron(1).py", line 69, in <module>
    excel(wbs, sheet, ligne_debut, colonne_debut, resultats)
  File "c:\Users\Paul\Documents\Applications\Traitement TDF\Entrée\Remplissage du Patron(1).py", line 33, in excel
    wbs.save(filename='Reporting.xls')
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 391, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 86, in write_data
    self._write_charts()
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 130, in _write_charts
    self._archive.writestr(chart.path[1:], tostring(chart._write()))
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\_chart.py", line 123, in _write
    container.view3D = chart.view3D
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 44, in __set__
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart._3d.View3D'>
```

**Bad solution** : I 've deleted pictures and graphs in all sheets and it is possible to write result file = "Reporting. xls"
**But I will have to include again pictures ans remake graphs...**

Other solution : Pandas put extra columns et raws with numbers. Bad result...
I leave this solution.

**Please : How to feed an Excel file with pictures and graphs ?
Spécial  libraries to import ?
Many thanks**

```
import io
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import xlwt
import os
import shutil
import pyexcel_xls,xlrd
from copy import deepcopy
from xlwt import Workbook, Formula
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import reader
from openpyxl import chartsheet
from openpyxl import chart


def excel(wbs, onglet, ligne_debut, colonne_debut, resultats): 
    # resultat est le contenu du fichier traité
    wb = Workbook()
    dest_filename = str(wbs)

    # copier 4 COLONNES !! 2 à 5 (2,6)
    nb_lignes = len(resultats)
    nb_colonnes = len(resultats[0])

    for row in range(nb_lignes):
        for col in range(nb_colonnes):
            value = resultats[row][col]
            _ = onglet.cell(
                column=colonne_debut + col, 
                row=ligne_debut + row, 
                 # recopie la ligne de resultat[y] [x] 
                 # Adressage relatif depuis coldeb, les colonnes démarrent ensuite de '0'
                value="{0}".format(value))
    wbs.save(filename='Reporting.xls')


wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Applications\Traitement Societe\Entrée\DaVimCi Societe rapport convergent des coûts_20190619.xls')
wbs = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Applications\Traitement Societe\Entrée\PATRON - Societe reporting financier en cours.xls') 
# print(wbs)
# fdavimci=wb.sheet_by_name('Parc DATA')
def resultats(ligne_debut,ligne_fin,fichier_entrée,name_sheet):
    feuille=fichier_entrée.sheet_by_name(name_sheet)
    n=ligne_debut
    resultats=[feuille.row(n)]
    while n<ligne_fin:
        resultats= resultats+[feuille.row(n+1)]
        n=n+1
    return resultats 

resultats= resultats(8,256,wb,'Parc DATA')
# print(resultats(8,12,wb,'Parc DATA'))


ligne_debut=8
colonne_debut=1

def get_sheet_by_name(workbook, name):
    matches = list(filter(lambda sheet: sheet.title==name, workbook.worksheets))
    if len(matches)==1:
        return matches[0]
    else:
        raise KeyError("Aucune feuille avec le nom '%s'"%name)

sheet = get_sheet_by_name(wbs, "Parc DATA")

excel(wbs, sheet, ligne_debut, colonne_debut, resultats)
```